# Why is Safari handoff so slow/doesn't work?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, ios, continuity

My iPhone 7 iOS 15.7 can see when my MacBook 15 macOS Monterey has bluetooth/wifi turned on, and a page open in Safari, because only in that situation does the "open ... from MacBook" appear at the bottom of the app selector.

However, after clicking it, Safari opens and a blue loading bar appears in the address bar, but the contents of the address bar are never filled and the blue loading bar never progresses.

I've tried basic things like turning on and off wifi and bluetooth on both devices and restarting both devices. I've been having this issue for a long time.

What could be causing it? How might I be able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the current iOS is 16.2, I would imagine it has something to do with your iOS being old. Many times I’ve had issues with compatibility between apple products until I upgraded to the current OS.

Comment: Yes, But Monterey is 2 years' old! The OS versions should be contemporary with each other, for best results, certainly.